# How can I show an overlay without the user having to click?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-plugins

When the user clicks on a button in a gridview, I will fetch some data and load it into some controls. I then want to show an overlay with this server-side content.

Has anyone used any nice jQuery plugins that do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: I just want to clarify what I need a bit more.

I've found plugins that do the job, but they are not flexible in that you have to specify a trigger that the user must click on for the overlay to appear.

What I'm looking for is a jQuery plugin that gives me a javascript function that I can call to show the overlay whenever I want. I can call this from the client-side or from the server side by registering the clientscript.

Comment: How is the content fetched? How does the code know the server-side code is complete?

Comment: @[lonesomeday] Thanks. I just clarified the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are several jQuery solutions to this, but if you're doing server-side stuff you want to display, you might want to look at the [PopupControl](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx) in the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/). I have no idea what the sample of this control is supposed to be doing (from my first link), but it does work in reality!

Comment: @[Graham Clark] Thanks for the link. I thought perhaps I could use jQuery and register the script so that I could also use it in other places from the client-side. I would prefer to do that if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Can the event fire on document ready?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// CODE HERE EXECUTES WHEN THE DOCUMENT IS READY

});
```

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready

Comment: @[Nick Pyett] Thanks. I just editied my question and clarified my scenario a bit. It will not be on Page_Load.